# Transcript without a start codon in mouse genome?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics

I am looking at the mouse reference genome in combination with ensemble annotation and am finding many transcripts that have no start codon.

For example, the transcript ENSMUST00000193149 at position 165503943-165567747. The first CDS has a frame number 1. In the UCSC genome browser, I see that in one of the tracks ADCY10 gene starts at this location, but in the protein sequence, there is an X under the first base, followed by a T under the next three (which indeed correspond to T).

I am puzzled: why does the transcript start at something other than the start codon? Why does the annotation indicate its start position as 165503943 instead of 165503944 where the actual codon starts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry in ensembl has a "CDS 5' incomplete" tag

http://uswest.ensembl.org/Mus_musculus/Transcript/Exons?db=core;g=ENSMUSG00000026567;r=1:165331512-165395316;t=ENSMUST00000193149